# Where can I change the HTML template for Sharepoint notification emails?

Tags: sharepoint

I´d like to change the appearance of Sharepoint (Portal Server 2003) email notifications that gets send when a new blog entry is made. Reason behind it: our company uses them like a newssystem and it would be nice if we could have some brand information (logo etc) and customized design in there.

I´m in the process of learning sharepoint so I just need a pointer in the right direction. But if somebody knows some more:
Is there one template for all notifications? Do I have to change it on the file level? Is there some kind of abstraction layer or API I can talk to? Themes?

I looked all over the tubes but found nothing at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WSS3, you modify the AlertTemplats.xml in the c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\1033\XML folder.  Just look trough the AlertTemplate nodes and find the name of the type of list that you want to modify.  I am not sure if this applies to SharePoint 2003, but I think it might.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer on the group microsoft.public.sharepoint.portalserver - haven´t tried it yet, but it seems possible on the template file level:

http://wssv3faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v3%20WSS%20FAQ/DispForm.aspx?ID=125